# keeping 2nd level navigation on first level li:hover visible

Tags: css, hover

We have horizontal 1st level and 2nd level navigations. When a 1st level li is hovered over, a second level ul is displayed horizontally above the first level ul.

How do we make the second level ul remain visible when the mouse leaves the first level li? Is this possible with CSS only..??

Here's the CSS:

```
ul.ebene1{display:inline;}
ul.ebene1 li{display:inline; list-style-type:none; margin-right:2%;}

ul.ebene2{display:none;}
ul.ebene1 li:hover ul.ebene2{display:block; position:fixed; bottom:6%; width:80%; font-size:0.9em;}
```

And the HTML:

```
<ul class="ebene1">
    <li><a href="">NAV1</a>
        <ul class="ebene2">
            <li><a href="">Nav2</a></li>
           <li><a href="">Nav2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">NAV1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">NAV1</a>
        <ul class="ebene2">
            <li><a href="">Nav2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Nav2</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">NAV1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't believe so. You're going to have to use JS, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with only CSS. The `:hover` pseudo classes is triggered when you *hover* the element. So when leaving the element stops the hover effect.

You could use JQuery to show the submenu.

**[EDIT]**
A Jquery solution would be this:

HTML

```
<ul class="ebene1">
    <li><a href="">NAV1</a>
        <ul class="ebene2">
            <li><a href="">Nav1.1</a></li>
           <li><a href="">Nav1.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">NAV2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">NAV3</a>
        <ul class="ebene2">
            <li><a href="">Nav3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Nav3.2</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">NAV4</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.ebene1 {
    display:inline;
}
ul.ebene1 li {
    display:inline;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-right:2%;
}
.ebene2 { 
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:6%;
    width:80%;
    font-size:0.9em;
}
```

JQuery

```
(".ebene1 li").mouseover( function() {
    if( $(this).children('ul').length > 0 ) // check if a ul exists in the li
    {
        $('.ebene2').hide(); // hide all submenus
        $(this).find('ul').show(); // show this submenu
    }
});
```

And a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/wYybh/).

Comment: Actually you are wrong, check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274097/keeping-top-level-menu-in-hover-state-when-moving-down-to-sub-menus

Comment: The question you refer to keeps the :hover effect on the parent when moving down its children. The TS wants to keep the children visible when moving out of the parent. (menu is positioned at the top op the page, submenu is positioned at the bottom of the page)